# Error running ThinkingSphinx with PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I used to have thinking-sphinx up and running with mySQL. Now, I migrate to PostgreSQL. However, my thinking-sphinx is still configured for mySQL, so got the following error:

```
    /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': no such file to load -- mysql2 (LoadError)
```

I trace back to `thinking_sphinx.rb` file in `Users/name/.rvm/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.1/lib` and found the following:

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM == 'java'
  require 'java'
  require 'jdbc/mysql'
else
  require 'mysql2'
end
```

How do I force `thinking-sphinx` to accept `pgsql`? 
Alternatively, do I need to uninstall `thinking-sphinx` and `Sphinx` completely and install them with configuration for `pgsql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues/413#issuecomment-11912232

> Thinking Sphinx v3 communicates with Sphinx using SphinxQL - which essentially means Sphinx behaves like a MySQL server. Hence, the mysql2 gem is required for sending queries to Sphinx.

So add this to you Gemfile

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Comment: You could also lock to before Thinking Sphinx 3.0.1 if installing all this mysql stuff is a pain in the ass: 
`gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.10'`